# Python, окно Tkinter поверх игры

Tags: python, tkinter, клавиатура

Пишу для себя небольшую программку на Питоне с использованием Tkinter и Keyboard, суть которой заключается в том, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку копировался ее текст. Пишу программу для игры WoT Blitz. Копирование текста кнопки я реализовал, но столкнулся с проблемой, что при нажатии горячих клавиш окно не появляется поверх игры и приходится закрывать окно игры, чтобы воспользоваться окном Tkinter.

Вот код программы:

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard

def openMeny():
    root = Tk() 
    root.title("app")
    root.geometry('300x200')
    root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
    root['bg'] = 'grey'
    root.lift()
    root.attributes('-topmost',True)
    root.after_idle(root.attributes,'-topmost',True)

btn1 = Button(root, text = 'WoT Blitz', font = ('comicsans', 10, 'bold'))
def btn1_def(event):
    btn1['activebackground'] = 'grey'
    text = btn1['text']
    root.clipboard_append(text)
btn1.bind('<Button-1>', btn1_def)

btn1.place(x = 5, y = 5)

mainloop()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + Win + t', openMeny)

keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Q')
```

Не могли бы вы пожалуйста подсказать, что можно сделать, чтобы это окно появлялось поверх игры? Пробовал воспользоваться 'root.lift() root.attributes('-topmost',True) root.after_idle(root.attributes,'-topmost',True)', но это не помогло. Буду очень благодарен за вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: несовсем то, но попробуйте прогу Deskpins. она делает любое окно поверх всех.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое! Сейчас попробую